# Pandas dataframe not saving after sort

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sort a dataframe by a column. I'm writing a function to return the top `n` amount of results from the `totals` column.

Here is my function:

```
def get_most(self, column, amt):
        most = OrderedDict()
        self.data = self.data.sort_values(by=[column])
        for i in range(amt):
            most.update({i : self.data.loc[i, :]})
        return most
```

When I call the function like so:

```
most_amt = self.get_most('Total', 3)
    for key, value in most_amt.items():
        print(key, value)
```

It returns the first 3 rows in the dataframe before the sort. I've also tried using the `inplace` attribute, like so:

```
self.data.sort_values(by=[column], inplace=True)
```

But to no avail.

The app itself is a little tracker I was making for myself to track the spread of the coronavirus. I'm using data from a github repo, and the input is a 312 row csv file. The first three rows are (I added the spaces on this question to make it easier to read, there are no spaces in the actual file):

```
Hubei,China,2020-03-21T10:13:08,67800,3139,58946
NaN,  Italy,2020-03-21T17:43:03,53578,4825, 6072
NaN,  Spain,2020-03-21T13:13:30,25374,1375, 2125
etc. etc
NaN,  China, 2020-03-23,        81305,3259,71857
NaN,  US,    2020-03-23,        25493, 307,  171
```

My expected output would then be:

```
NaN,  China, 2020-03-23,        81305,3259,71857
NaN,  Italy,2020-03-21T17:43:03,53578,4825, 6072
NaN,  US,    2020-03-23,        25493, 307,  171
```

Instead, it is just the first three rows of the CSV.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show your input & expected output?

Comment: @Datanovice updated!

Comment: Why the approach with the OrderedDict?  Why not just sort the data frame and return the first n rows either as a new data frame or reference to indices or such?

Comment: @JeffH I don't necessarily know why I chose that approach, it was just what came to me. Doing what you said still returns the first 3 rows in the frame instead of the sorted values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the right approach...  Realize the command in In[20] will return a new data frame.

```
In [17]: data = {'zone':['us', 'italy', 'china', 'south pole'], 
    ...:         'qty': [ 10, 40, 12, 3]}                                       

In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)                                                

In [19]: df                                                                     
Out[19]: 
         zone  qty
0          us   10
1       italy   40
2       china   12
3  south pole    3

In [20]: df.sort_values('qty', ascending=False)[:3]    #top 3                   
Out[20]: 
    zone  qty
1  italy   40
2  china   12
0     us   10
```

Comment: That worked! Can you explain why you used ascending=False?

Comment: Look in the pandas documentation for details.  The default sort order is ascending (least to greatest), so I wanted top 3, so I changed the default.  Note, I could have done the default sort and just asked for the *last* 3 elements of the result too.